# How to check which TLS version my java web service client is using?

Tags: wireshark, tls1.2, java-6

I have to fix a client Java application in order to use TLSv1.2 instead of old versions. I have to test comparing the code before the fix (when the default TLS for java 6 is supposed to be used) and after. The problem is with the 'before' scenario, when I check the connection through Wireshark, I see TLSv1.2 protocol, despite the client using Java 1.6 and JAVA_HOME set to the same java version (see [here](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/tls-and-java/): java 6 does not support TLSv1.2).

[image]

Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how can I test (programmaticaly or not) what is the real TLS version my client is using?

Comment: What makes you think this is wrong?

Comment: @Eric "client using Java 1.6 and JAVA_HOME set to the same java version"
Java 6 does not support TLSv1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I used Netbeans to run it/opened cmd through Netbeans and executed `java -r JarToExecute.jar`, which had java 8 set. Opened cmd from start menu and then Wireshark displayed the correct TLS version 1.